# TFS check in policy to enforce work item but also allow non work item related check ins

Tags: tfs, checkin

I would like to enforce the policy to associate TFS check ins with a work item from TFS but we do also have work that comes from other streams that doesn't have a TFS work item and still need to be able to check these in.

Is there a way to do this, would also be nice to prompt the non work item related check-ins to add information about the check-in.

Would we be talking about some sort of custom policy here? Possibly dummy PBI,SBT to use for the other types?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even if you configure the policy to be used, it is possible to override a policy if you encounter a violation when you check-in. The dialog also asks you to add a separate comment (though this is optional). As far as I understand your desired behavior, this would solve your requirements. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245460%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the detailed steps.

Another approach to solve this is to move the items that do not require a checkin policy to another TFS Team Project.